# JavaScript on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile

iOS has the JavaScriptCore engine - developed and maintained by Apple, officially endorsed and included into the SDK by them since iOS 7.

**What are the for official, built-in or otherwise 'most native' / 'easiest included/installed' JavaScript engines for (latest versions of) Android and Windows phone, respectively?**

..jailbreak, rooting or otherwise strong-arming the device excluded

Comment: More specifically, what are the **Browser-independent** libraries for each mobile OS?

Answer (score 0):

Chakra -  Windows (IE)
v8  - Android(chrome)
Rhino -mozilla
JavaScriptCore - Apple

Hope your question got answered.

Comment: I'm going to assume you meant: Chakra - Windows (IE); v8 - Android(chrome); Rhino -mozilla; JavaScriptCore - Apple
In which case: 1) What's "mozilla" -- FirefoxOS? 2) I see you mention web browsers in (brackets). JavaScriptCore is stand-alone and independent of the Safari browser, are there such solutions for the other OSes too?

Comment: @zra These JS engine used by the OS for browser rendering. Thats y mentioned those browser name in bracket for better understanding.